# BufferedReader not reading data correctly

Tags: java, input, tcp, stream, bufferedreader

I have a TCP-server client pair. The client has a thread for Handling the data which comes from the server. the problem is, before the first data is received from the server, the Buffered reader is blocked. But once the first data is received, it keeps sending 0's in between the usefull data. Does anyone have any idea why? And how to solve this?

```
    connection = new Socket(ip, port);
    output = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

And this part is modified to handle the 0's, yet this isn't ideal:

```
 try {
                opcode = (char) input.read();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ErrorFrame erfframe = new ErrorFrame("De verbinding is verbroken voordat we de opcode van het packet konden lezen", "Herverbinden", IRIGui.ConnectionType);
            }
            System.out.println("Data received!!" + opcode);
            int opcodenr = Character.getNumericValue(opcode);
            char sensortype = '0';
            try {
                do {
                    sensortype = (char) input.read();
                } while (sensortype == 0);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ErrorFrame erfframe = new ErrorFrame("De verbinding is verbroken voordat we de sensortype van het packet konden lezen", "Herverbinden", IRIGui.ConnectionType);
            }
```

The server code:

public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(25566);

```
while (true) {
    Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
    BufferedReader inFromClient =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
    DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
    int request = inFromClient.read();
    System.out.println("erjioejfioe " + request);
    if (request == 4) {
        outToClient.writeBytes("41");
        outToClient.write(5);
        outToClient.writeInt(5);
        outToClient.writeInt(3);
        outToClient.writeInt(6);
        outToClient.writeInt(5);
        outToClient.writeInt(1);
    }
    request = 0;
    request = inFromClient.read();
    System.out.println("erjioejfioe " + request);
    if (request == 4) {
        System.out.println("SENDING THE SHIT");
        outToClient.writeBytes("41");
        outToClient.write(5);
        outToClient.writeInt(3);
        outToClient.writeInt(7);
        outToClient.writeInt(2);
        outToClient.writeInt(4);
        outToClient.writeInt(3);
        System.out.println("We get here!!");
    }
    break;
}
```

}

Comment: What does the sending code look like? and why are you surprised that the read blocks until something has been sent?

Comment: I added the server code. I am not surprised it blocks, cause it should. But I am surprised it doesn't anymore after the first data is received

Comment: There is no evidence here of anything not blocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing ints, which are 32 bits, and in your case all have three leading zero bytes, and reading chars, which are 16 bits, so every odd char you read consists of two zero bytes. This doesn't make any sense. If you write with `writeInt()`, read with `readInt()`. Same goes for all the other `DataInput/OutputStream` methods. Use them symmetrically.

There is no evidence here of anything not blocking.